# Dompdf relative/absolute positioned items with percentages not acting as expected

Tags: css, laravel, wkhtmltopdf, dompdf

I'm using dompdf in laravel, there is a section of my PDF where I need to create a graph using a passed variable into my blade.

I have a calculation turning that variable into a percentage of its max number:

```
$bar_percentage = (($bar - 5) * 100) / (20);
```

The upshot of it is, I have a percentage number that I need to create the height of a bar in a bar graph. I had a different way of doing it previously using flexbox when we were using wkhtmltopdf directly, but it was problematic across environments so we added dompdf and I needed to refactor the pdf blade to use tables. My idea was to create the background of the graph using a 3-row table, and absolutely position the bar within it, something like this:

```
  <div class="graph-container">
    <div class="bar" style="height:<?= $bar_percentage; ?>%"></div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: green;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: yellow;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: red;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

then absolutely position the bar within the table:

```
<style>
  .graph-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .graph-container table td {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .bar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>
```

But something super weird happens. First of all, the "bottom" puts both the table and the bar way below the `graph-container` (but not at the bottom of the `graph-container`'s parent element, even lower than that!)

Also, the height of the bar should be a percentage of the height of `graph-container` but it is much larger than the graph container when I set that percentage to 100%, and I can't figure out what element it is comparing its percentage to!!!

any help is welcome! Thank you.

It's definitely something weird going on with Dompdf and absolute/relative positioning but i can't tell how to get around it. If I could ensure that the height of the bar would at least be a percentage of the correct height then I could hack it to the correct position, but the bar size is way incorrect as well.

Comment: Actually the problem is not clear,  `$bar_percentage` give you your expected output?

Comment: It gives me the correct percentage number, however the height of the bar is not being set as a percentage of its parent component. So i have `div 1` with `bar` inside of it, bar should be 50% of height of div 1 but it's even bigger than div 1 even though it's correctly displaying as `height: 50%`

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with DomPdf only px is available take a look on the docs.